# The growth of the Hilbert function of a graded ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, hilbert-function, graded-rings-modules

Let $A=\bigoplus A_i$ be a finitely generated commutative unital graded algebra over a field $k$. Let $d(i)=\dim A_i$.

In general $d(i)$ is not a polynomial in $i$ (even not eventually polynomial). However, there is a number $D$ s.t. for any large enough $i_0$ the function $d(i_0+iD)$ is polynomial in $i$ (for positive $i$). In other words the Hilbert-Poincare power series $P(t)=\sum d(i)t^i$ is a rational function whose poles are roots of unity (see e.g. https://people.kth.se/~laksov/courses/algebradr01/notes/grading2.pdf theorem 2.10).

We are interested in the growth of the function $d(i)$. As we understand, $\limsup\left(\frac{\ln(d(i)}{\ln(i)}\right)$ is the dimension of $Spec(A)$. We need a reference for this fact. We do have an argument but it is not very short, so if there is no reference a short proof will be also helpful.

Comment: I guess you mean commutative ring? Aren't these facts in Matsumura or Eisenbud's books?

Comment: Yes I mean commutative. I have corrected it. I will have look at those books. Thank you

Comment: By "the dimension of $Spec(A)$" I guess you mean Krull? Yeah, I don't think this is going to be that short. When I prove this in class (that "Hilbert dimension" = "Krull dimension") it's got three parts. First, modding out a nilpotent doesn't change either dimension. Second, if there are no nilpotents, then when we break into components either dimension = max(dim of components). Third, if $f\in A_{k>0}$ is not a zero divisor, then killing $f$ decreases both dimensions by $1$. (I guess there's a zeroth part for the base case of this induction.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was hoping that it will be easy to deduce the statement above from "Hilbert dimension" = "Krull dimension". The statement above is slightly different since we do not demand that the ring will be generated by elements in degree 1.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for replying to such an old question. I needed a similar result for my research and felt like it could be useful to answer if people were to need an answer too. Since I couldn't find a reference, I included an argument in a preprint of mine. It can be found [here (arXiv:2210.12793)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.12793). The result is Proposition 8.6 (page 32), and it uses the notation $O^{\sharp}$ introduced in Notation 2.3 (page 4), which basically means the thing you were expecting about $\limsup \frac{\log d(n)}{log(n)}$. Specifically, I write $f(n)=O^{\sharp}(g(n))$ to mean that $f$ is a $O(g)$ but not a $o(g)$.

**Proposition 8.6:** let $A$ be a finitely generated graded commutative $k$-algebra ($k$ is a field) of nonzero Krull dimension. *We do not assume that $A$ is generated by elements of degree $1$.* Then its Hilbert function $\mathrm{HF}_A(n)=\dim_k(A_n)$ satisfies $\mathrm{HF}_A(n) = O^{\sharp}(n^{\dim_{\text{Krull}} A - 1})$.

As I remark in the paper, this is conceptually close to the fact that the [Gelfand-Kirillov dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Kirillov_dimension) of an algebra of finite type over a field is equal to its Krull dimension, but it does not seem to directly follow from that.